# Downloading photos problem

Tags: digital

My computer will not accept my memory card, Photos are on the card yet the card reader says  no photos to show on this device, I am stuck with pictures I cannot edit, or indeed see, tried all the obvious tricks to no avail,**HELP*

Comment: We need a lot more information in order to help. What kind of card is it, and what kind of computer? What exactly is the error message? What "obvious tricks" did you try?

Comment: Knowing what kind of camera and whether the camera and computer have the latest software, etc., would help.

Comment: Do the pictures display properly on the camera?

Comment: vtc b/c This is primarily a computer problem that photographers would not *necessarily* be expected to have any expertise in.  This Q is better suited for superuser.SE or one of the OS-specific SEs.

Answer (score 10):

The words "no photos to show on this device" suggests your computer is running software that is looking for a certain type of file which it knows to be "photos".

If instead you use a file manager (for example Windows Explorer, Dolphin, Finder), it's possible you would see files that the software isn't recognising as photographs - proprietary RAW formats being a common example. If you can see the files on the card using a file manager, looking at the file type (suffix) will give you a term to put into a search engine to find a compatible viewer.

If a file manager is not able to see the files, the issue could be card format (for example not all operating systems support exFAT by default). Your preferred search engine will tell you how to enable file operations on this type of file structure with your operating system.

Answer (score 8):

> Photos are on the card yet the card reader says no photos to show on this device

If your camera can see the photos, then you might try connecting the camera to the computer and downloading the photos that way. Most digital cameras have a USB port for direct connection to a computer. This is often not quite as fast as using a dedicated card reader, but reading the photos slowly is better than not at all.